# Remove Object from Array in MongoDB given ID

Tags: javascript, arrays, database, mongodb, mongoose

I am making an application that works with playlists. I am using MongoDB with mongoose and storing videos in each playlist via an array, like so:

```
{
  _id: ObjectId("61ca1d0ddb66b3c5ff93df9c")
  name: "Playlist A"
  videos: [
    { 
      title: "Video 1",
      url: "www.YouTube.com/video1", 
      startTime: "20",
      endTime: "40", 
      _id: ObjectId("61ca1d1ddb66b3c5ff93e0ba")
    },
    ...
  ]
}
```

I want to be able to remove a video from a playlist based on the `_id` of a video. I have tried looking online for solutions but the solutions I've found don't work. This is what I am trying:

```
Playlist.updateOne(
    { _id: req.params.playlistId },
    { $pull: { videos: { _id: req.params.vidId } } }
  )
```

When I run the code above and log the result I get the following (not sure if this is relevant):

```
{
  acknowledged: true,
  modifiedCount: 1,
  upsertedId: null,
  upsertedCount: 0,
  matchedCount: 1
}
```

Please let me know if you need any more information this is my first time posting a question :)

Comment: A nice tip: store videos and playlists separately. and in playlists document, store the id of a video

Comment: your query is correct, verify that the `req.params.vidId` variable corresponds to the value `ObjectId("61ca1d1ddb66b3c5ff93e0ba")` of type `ObjectId`

Comment: @hhharsha36 Yes!!! That was the issue, just had to wrap `req.params.vidId` with `ObjectId()`. I thought that mongoose automatically did this but I guess I was wrong. Thank you so much!

Comment: @DarthApprentice that is an interesting idea and I've seen others do that. Why is storing video ids preferable? Wouldn't this make it more complicated when it comes to accessing each video, as I would have to search for each video by their id rather than just having the videos already there in the array?

Answer (score 0):

This is a TypeError `req.params.vidId` returns a string and mongoose is looking for Type `ObjectId`. The solution is to convert the string literal (`req.params.vidId`) to an `ObjectId`, like so:

```
Playlist.updateOne(
    { _id: req.params.playlistId },
    { $pull: { videos: { _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.vidId) } } }
  )
```